# What causes the flash of grey when I click on an input on my iPhone?

Tags: html, css

Using my iPhone to preview a webpage I'm working on, I notice that whenever I click an input, I see a brief flash of grey behind it.

I've stripped out all the CSS but the grey flashing remains. It's not visible on desktop Safari, only mobile Safari.

What is causing it? How do I stop it from happening?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Why do the inputs flash?</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    input {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
      border-radius: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="radio" name="mode" id="mode1" value="mode1">
  <label for="mode1">Mode 1</label>

  <input type="radio" name="mode" id="mode2" value="mode2">
  <label for="mode2">Mode 2</label>

  <input type="radio" name="mode" id="mode3" value="mode3">
  <label for="mode3">Mode 3</label>

  <label for="hello">
    <input checked type="checkbox" id="hello">
    <span class="toggle">
      <span class="switch"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="label">Check me</span>
  </label>
  
  <form action="">
    <label for="text-input">
      Enter text
      <input type="text">
    </label>

    <label for="email-iput">
      Enter email here
      <input type="email">
    </label>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: grey flashing inputs]

Comment: Have you tried it with absolutely zero css?

Comment: I'd recommend posting a markup image of the flash you are talking about since we can't really view an iPhone view in any code playground. Doing this will help better answer your question.

Comment: Yes. The flash is still there without the CSS. I added the styling to make it easier to see.

Comment: I suggest wrapping your `label` around the checkbox and a `span` or `p` with the text in it. The problem is that you've stretched the `input` across the entire screen; technically, the radio/check should be stretched as well, but since they are drawn by the OS as square, they are only stretched when clicked.

Answer (score 5):

I googled the American spelling *gray* and found an [answer](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/remove-gray-highlight-when-tapping-links-in-mobile-safari/) on CSS-tricks.

> `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);`
> And then to allow `:active styles` to work in your CSS on a page in Mobile Safari:
> `document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){}, true);`

**Edit**

Actually, I only need `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);` to override the grey flash.

Comment: Work like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: block;`

### Tested in the newest Safari Version in IOS 15

Here's an example:

```css
/* Ignore this */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Width part */

#first {
  display: block;
  background: red;
}

#second {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p id="first">This has a 100% width</p>

<br>

<p id="second">This text has a background color based on the texts lenght</p>
```

So change this:

```
input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

to this:

```
input {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
   border-radius: 0px;
}
```

or just this:

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Still results in a flash of grey for me. FWIW, I'm using 14.8

Answer (score 0):

Radio and checkbox elements should not use width property in the sense you are using it. It should be fixed element size whatever it is. If you want it to take up an entire row, you should wrap it in a div. As bellow.

However, there might be a CSS way to manage the color via the use of :focus selector. But I cannot test it, since I don't have access to iPhone.

```
input:focus {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Why do the inputs flash?</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    input {
      display: block;
      border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
      border-radius: 0px;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="i-should-be-full-width">
    <input type="radio" name="mode" id="mode1" value="mode1">
  </div>
  <label for="mode1">Mode 1</label>

  <input type="radio" name="mode" id="mode2" value="mode2">
  <label for="mode2">Mode 2</label>

  <input type="radio" name="mode" id="mode3" value="mode3">
  <label for="mode3">Mode 3</label>

  <label for="hello">
    <input checked type="checkbox" id="hello">
    <span class="toggle">
      <span class="switch"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="label">Check me</span>
  </label>
  
  <form action="">
    <label for="text-input">
      Enter text
      <input type="text">
    </label>

    <label for="email-iput">
      Enter email here
      <input type="email">
    </label>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I removed the `width` styling but I still get the grey flash. I've also tried styling the background colour `input:focus` but the grey flash remains.

Comment: Then I cannot help you, this is out of my bounds, sorry.